# SharePoint 2013 document generation from list items using workflow

Tags: workflow, document-template

I have been able to generate docs from list items using sharepoint designer workflow.But i have been able to do this with using one document template.
But i have like 6 templates i would like to use what do i need to do to get this rolling would i need to have 6 different doc libs with a doc template?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You might just need 1 document library with 6 content types and 6 templates.

Comment: I have created a doc with multiple content type and 6 templates but I noticed when I try and add a column with a number data type via the document properties it doesn't show up.

Any ideas?